# Input Impedance Question

Tags: datasheet, input-impedance

As I look at the Datasheet of a differential amplifier for input impedance, i see below statement.
[image]

0.8||2 for Differential.
0.4||2 for Common mode.

What does GΩ||pF mean?

Comment: I'd assume Gigohms in parallel with picofarads - the input looks like a high value resistor in parallel with a tiny capacitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input resistance, expressed in GigaOhms; in parallel with stray capacitance, expressed in PicoFarads